# Android Camera2 API development/getting started basics with manual control

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm attempting to build an Android application that implements the Camera2 API with manual controls and whatnot. However. since I'm kind of new to programming and Android developement in general, I don't really understand what exactly I need to accomplish this.

It would be awesome if someone could perhaps outline for me in simple terms what my app needs to contain in order for it to launch and take a picture with specified settings.

Thanks!

Comment: I have actually had a look through the "L Camera" open-source application but it appears to be highly complicated and difficult to understand exactly.

Comment: It's recommended to goto the following link ...if you wanna learn about Camera2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html Besides that you can visit my Github library for custom use of Camera2 API https://github.com/attiqrehman1991/Camera-3

Comment: google really dropped the ball here. nothing, i mean nothing in the doc shows how to use it. i am tight on timeline. I might just use the old one.